# Show more posts in Wordpress sidebar (like YouTube)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to create a YouTube Esque sidebar 'Show More' button.

The posts from the same category are displayed in my template sidebar using the following code:

```
<div class="sidebar-left">
    <div class="grid-container">
        <?php
                global $post;
                $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
                $current_cat = $category[0]->cat_name;

                $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name='.$current_cat.'&showposts=10');
                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                        <div class="grid-item-meta">
                                <span><?php echo $entry_cats; ?></span>
                                <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                                <h5>Written by <?php echo get_the_author(); ?></h5>
                        </div>
                </a>
                <?php endwhile;
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to limit this query / offset it and fetch more on clicking a 'Show More' button. Once show more has been toggled I need to change it to 'Show Less'. I'm quite happy pulling all posts in one query and hiding them on the front end (i'm not too concerned with getting into complex AJAX).

Limiting the height of the `div` could cut off a post in the middle. Seems there is lots of info / answers on loading more mosts via AJAX or loading a post in a particular div, however not a simple show and hide scenario like I'm after. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind loading all the posts you could use some jQuery to get that effect. Check out the CodePen link.

https://codepen.io/pen/QvOpGK

declare at which point you will hide posts, 4 will be the first post we hide

```
#posts div:nth-child(n + 4) {
  display: none;
}
```

Then use jQuery to show posts on click, I'm adding a class `show` that gives a `display: block;`

```
//We need to tell jQuery which posts to show in hiddenPosts

var hiddenPosts = $('#posts div:nth-child(n + 4)');

var button = $('#showMore');

$(button).click(function() {

  hiddenPosts.toggleClass( 'show' );

  //change button's text

  if (button.text() == "Show More") {
    button.text("Show Less");
  } else {
    button.text("Show More");
  }

});
```

Comment: Looks like exactly why I'm after. How could I animate this to slide the div extension? Transition on the css class or jQuery?

Comment: I forked my pen to include an animation. https://codepen.io/sketchbookkeeper/pen/zwPpQm. essentially we just use the `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` jQuery functions on the selected posts after checking if they are showing or not.